# How drools to iterate over a list

Tags: list, drools

I'm new to Drools6.4.0.FINAL and want to use it to iterate over a list of items and process my business logic

my business data return List ,I want insert it into KieSession

```
List<MyObject> list = service.queryList(Map<String,Object> param);
kSession.insert(list);
kSession.fireAllRules();
```

my drl file like this :

```
import java.util.List;
import xxx.xxx.MyObject;

rule "rule 1"
salience 1 
activation-group "ctoc_order_rule"
when
    $mo:MyObject(orgunitid_lev1 == 58094);
then
    $mo.setBusiness_type_id(201);
    $mo.setBusiness_type_name("business201");
    update($mo);
end
```

But this not fire my rules,How can I do to fire a List ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a `java.util.List`, insert a List and write a pattern `List(...)`.

If you want to match a `xxx.xxx.MyObject`, insert a MyObject and write a pattern `MyObject(...)`.

If you insert a List and have pattern `MyObject(...)`, it cannot match. It would be possible to match a List and extract the elements (using `from`), but matching (generic) container classes is somewhat of an anti-pattern. What if you have several kinds of List containing various object?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't think so. What about inserting the MyObject objects?